# Abbyy Flexicapture SDK : How to save and update vendor record in dataSets using Java?

Tags: abbyy, abbyy-cloud-ocr

I am saving data in IDataSetTableRecords in name column then it is saving in all the index like name, name1 and name2. In IDataSetTableRecords  only one method setField("columnName","columnValue") how to saving these data in different index ?

IDataSet dataSet = documentDefinition.getDataSets().Find("", Vendor.VENDORS);
IDataSetTableRecord dataSetTableRecord = dataSet.getTableRecords().getElement(0);                           dataSetTableRecord.setField(columnName, vendor.getName());